# SQL - Can you filter by datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm looking at a database of mobile numbers and am trying to find errors.

For example, mobile numbers begin with '04', so to test for errors, I can query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Names.Phone_M FROM Names
WHERE Names.Phone_M NOT LIKE '04%'
```

In testing for errors, I noticed some of the data contains text. Is there a way of filtering the data so it only brings up entries than contain some kind of text as well as numbers? i.e. If an entry is '0400000000 - John', can I write a query that will pick this up without simple trial and error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  ISNUMERIC () function

`where ISNUMERIC (Names.Phone_M) = 1 -- should match valid numbers`

`where ISNUMERIC (Names.Phone_M) = 0 -- should match invalid numbers`

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to check if the phones have characters other than numbers in them.

`[^0-9]` finds any characters other than 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phone_M 
FROM Names
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Phone_M) > 0
AND Phone_M LIKE '04%'
```

Generalizing the above to find all phones which can have numbers as well as text, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phone_M 
FROM Names
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Phone_M) > 0
AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Phone_M) > 0
```